# Start rails server automatically when ever I start my ubuntu machine

Tags: linux, ruby-on-rails-3, shell, scripting, ubuntu

I have a rails application and I want to start the server automatically whenever the machine boots up. Right now I cd to the directory and then type the `rails s` command. How can I configure my machine to run my Rail server on boot? I am using Ubuntu and Rails 3.0.0.

Comment: can you share your stack (ex. Apache 2, mongrel etc.)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a cron job for this. To add the cron job use the command `crontab -e`. Than you can define a cron job that runs at boot and reboot with `@reboot command`.

So you'd have something like:

```
@reboot cd /home/[path to project] && rails server
```

Comment: i did the crontab -e and added the command u give with my correct path but it didnt work ..is there something am missing too ?

Comment: You can always test the command manualy to see if that gives errors

Answer (score 5):

```
@reboot /bin/bash -l -c 'cd PATH_TO_PROJECT && rails s'
```

did the trick for me. You might need to reload **RVM** and for that

```
@reboot /bin/bash -l -c 'cd PATH_TO_PROJECT && source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm && rvm use ruby-RUBY_VERSION_HERE && rails s'
```

will serve the purpose.

Comment: In my case it was different location for rvm `source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh` and this worked. Thanks!