# How to start Puma app after restart Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, puma

I have a Ruby on Rails application which runs on Ubuntu server with Puma. I deploy my application with Capistrano and everything works well.

But when I restart ubuntu server, Rails application is not running. How can I start puma after system restart? Can I add & control Puma like system service on Ubuntu?

Comment: You might find an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563714/start-rails-server-automatically-when-ever-i-start-my-ubuntu-machine